# TCP/IP .NET and PLC communicaton

Tags: c#, .net, plc

I have written a WinForms program in C# for testing products. At the moment I'm operating all the mechanical aspects of the machine i.e.: move UUT to test position, engage test probes, etc.. I have control over every aspect and that's how I progress my test sequence.

I'm using an NI DAQ and some custom made PCBs, I'm communicating with UUT over UART on SerialPort, and I'm collecting some data into a Database.

Now, I need to bring in a new gen. machine which will be operated by a PLC, so my job will be easier; the PLC will set up everything, then I'll communicate with the PLC to do my tests. I need to communicate with the PLC over TCP/IP.

What would be involved in communicating with the PLC over TCP/IP? Obviously I'd have to set up a server, establish a connection with the PLC, and develop some communication protocol, so I can update test steps on my screen and such. I've never done any TCP/IP comms. before.

If it helps, it's an Omron PLC NX1P2, and they want me to re-use the protocol they developed on another machine, which interacts with LabVIEW and TestStand.

This is what they have written in StructuredText; it runs on the PLC:

```
// Start sequence when Trigger changes to TRUE.
IF ( (Enable=TRUE) AND (DoTCP=FALSE) AND (_Eip_EtnOnlineSta=TRUE) ) THEN
    DoTCP:=TRUE;
        
    IF (TCP_Conn_Status = _CLOSED) OR (TCP_Conn_Status = _CLOSE_WAIT) OR (TCP_Conn_Status = _CLOSING)  THEN //(TCP_Conn_Status <> _ESTABLISHED) THEN
        Stage := 1; //try connect if not estabilished yet
    ELSE
        Stage:=2;   //only check status, avoid open another port and lose sync.     
    END_IF;
    
    SktTCPConnect_instance(Execute:=FALSE);  // Initialize instance.
    SktClearBuf_instance(Execute:=FALSE);  // Initialize instance.
    SktGetTCPStatus_instance(Execute:=FALSE);  // Initialize instance.
    SktTCPSend_instance(  // Initialize instance.
        Execute:=FALSE,
        SendDat:= dummy_dat[0]);  // Dummy
    SktTCPRcv_instance(  // Initialize instance.
        Execute:=FALSE,
        RcvDat :=dummy_dat[0]);  // Dummy
    SktClose_instance(Execute:=FALSE);  // Initialize instance.
END_IF;

IF (DoTCP=TRUE) THEN
    
    CASE Stage OF
            
        1:  // Request a connection.
            SktTCPConnect_instance(
                Execute   :=TRUE,
                SrcTcpPort:=UINT#0,  // Local TCP port number: Automatically assigned.
                DstAdr    :=IP_Address,  // Remote IP address
                DstTcpPort:=Remote_Port,  // Destination TCP port number
                Socket =>TCP_Conn_WkSocket);  // Socket     
                
            IF (SktTCPConnect_instance.Done=TRUE) THEN
                Stage:=INT#2;  //check TCP status               
            ELSIF (SktTCPConnect_instance.Error=TRUE) THEN
                error_ID := (SktTCPConnect_instance.ErrorID);
                //TCP_Conn_Status := _CLOSED;
                IF (error_ID = WORD#16#2008) THEN //never lock error to else state
                    Stage:=INT#6; //errorID=2008 - Socket Communications Resource Overflow
                ELSE
                    Stage:=INT#2;  // always check TCP status
                END_IF; 
                        
            END_IF;
            

        2: //request status
            SktGetTCPStatus_instance(
                Execute:=TRUE,
                Socket :=TCP_Conn_WkSocket);  // Socket
                            
            IF (SktGetTCPStatus_instance.Done) THEN
                TCP_Conn_Status := SktGetTCPStatus_instance.TcpStatus;
                IF (TCP_Conn_Status <> _ESTABLISHED) THEN //(TCP_Conn_Status = _CLOSED) OR (TCP_Conn_Status = _CLOSE_WAIT) OR (TCP_Conn_Status = _CLOSING) THEN
                    Stage:=INT#0;   //go to end
                ELSE
                    Stage:=INT#3;   //continue normal flow
                END_IF;
                                                    
            ELSIF (SktGetTCPStatus_instance.Error=TRUE) THEN
                error_ID:=(SktGetTCPStatus_instance.ErrorID);
                Stage:=INT#20; // Error end
            END_IF;
                
        3:   //  sending message
            Payload_local:= Payload_Client_IN;  
                        
            Msg_size_byte := CRC_size_byte + ToAryByte(Payload_local,_LOW_HIGH,SendSocketDat[0]) + UINT#2;  ////payload size + CRC (bytes)
            Msg_size:= ToAryByte(Msg_size_byte,_LOW_HIGH,SendSocketDat[0]);     //replace first two bytes with payload  + CRC size 
            Msg_size_byte :=ToAryByte(Payload_local,_LOW_HIGH,SendSocketDat[2]);    //replace rest of the array with palyload as bytes
            
            Payload_CRC_send := AryCRCCCITT(SendSocketDat[0],(Msg_size_byte+Msg_size),WORD#0,_LOW_HIGH);        //calculates (size +payload) CRC
            Msg_size_CRC :=ToAryByte(Payload_CRC_send,_LOW_HIGH,SendSocketDat[Msg_size_byte+Msg_size]); //append CRC as bytes to the end of the array
            
            SktTCPSend_instance(
                Execute:=TRUE,
                Socket :=TCP_Conn_WkSocket,  // Socket
                SendDat:= SendSocketDat[0],// TCP_Message_Send[0],  // Send data
                Size   := Msg_size_byte+Msg_size+Msg_size_CRC); // msg payload + payload size + CRC 16
                
            IF (SktTCPSend_instance.Done=TRUE) THEN
                Stage:=INT#4;  // go to read buffer
                SktTCPSend_instance(  // reinitialize instance.
                    Execute:=FALSE,
                    SendDat:= dummy_dat[0]);
                SktTCPRcv_instance( //reset instance
                    Execute:=FALSE,
                    RcvDat :=dummy_dat[0]);
                
            ELSIF (SktTCPSend_instance.Error=TRUE) THEN             
                error_ID:=( SktTCPSend_instance.ErrorID);               
                IF (error_ID =  WORD#16#2006) THEN // OR error_ID = WORD#16#2003) THEN
                    Stage:=INT#5;  // time out - clear buffer only
                ELSE
                    Stage:=INT#30;  // Error end
                END_IF;
                                        
            END_IF;
            
                                
        4:  // Request receiving message size only
            SktTCPRcv_instance(
                Execute:=TRUE,
                Socket :=TCP_Conn_WkSocket,  // Socket
                TimeOut:=UINT#10,  // Timeout time: 1 x (0.1 sec)
                Size   :=UINT#2,  // Receive data size
                RcvDat := RcvSocketDat[0]);  // Receive data
         
            IF (SktTCPRcv_instance.Done=TRUE) THEN              
                Stage:=INT#41;  // Normal end
                SktTCPRcv_instance( //reset instance
                    Execute:=FALSE,
                    RcvDat :=dummy_dat[0]);
                                
            ELSIF (SktTCPRcv_instance.Error=TRUE) THEN              
                error_ID:=(SktTCPRcv_instance.ErrorID);             
                IF (error_ID =  WORD#16#2006) THEN // OR error_ID = WORD#16#2003) THEN
                    Stage:=INT#5;  // time out - clear buffer only              
                ELSE
                    Stage:=INT#40;
                END_IF;
                
            END_IF;
            
        41: // Request receiving payload
            
            AryByteTo (RcvSocketDat[0],UINT#2,_LOW_HIGH,Msg_size_byte_send);    //convert byte array to message size
            
            SktTCPRcv_instance(
                Execute:=TRUE,
                Socket :=TCP_Conn_WkSocket,  // Socket
                TimeOut:=UINT#10,  // Timeout time 10 x 0.1s - 1sec
                Size   :=Msg_size_byte_send,  // Receive data size
                RcvDat := RcvSocketDat[2]);  // Receive data
         
            IF (SktTCPRcv_instance.Done=TRUE) THEN
                Stage:=INT#5;  // normal end
                
                Payload_CRC_receive_recalc:= AryCRCCCITT(RcvSocketDat[0],Msg_size_byte_send,WORD#0,_LOW_HIGH);  //calculate CRC from received message (add size, but exclude CRC on the payload)
                AryByteTo(RcvSocketDat[Msg_size_byte_send],UINT#2,_LOW_HIGH,Payload_CRC_receive);
                IF (Payload_CRC_receive = Payload_CRC_receive_recalc) then
                    payload_received:=AryByteTo(RcvSocketDat[2],Msg_size_byte_send - UINT#2,_LOW_HIGH,Payload_Server_OUT);  //convert array of bytes to dta type, excluding msg size and CRC
                END_IF;
                
            ELSIF (SktTCPRcv_instance.Error=TRUE) THEN              
                error_ID:=(SktTCPRcv_instance.ErrorID);             
                IF (error_ID =  WORD#16#2006) THEN // OR error_ID = WORD#16#2003) THEN
                    Stage:=INT#5;  // time out - clear buffer only              
                ELSE
                    Stage:=INT#410;
                END_IF;
                
            END_IF;
            
            
         5:  // Clear receive buffer.
            SktClearBuf_instance(
                Execute:=TRUE,
                Socket :=TCP_Conn_WkSocket);  // Socket
         
            IF (SktClearBuf_instance.Done=TRUE) THEN
                Stage:=INT#0;  // check connection
            ELSIF (SktClearBuf_instance.Error=TRUE) THEN
                error_ID:=(SktClearBuf_instance.ErrorID);
                Stage:=INT#50;  // Error end
            END_IF;
     
        6:  // Request closing.
            SktClose_instance(
                Execute:=TRUE,
                Socket :=TCP_Conn_WkSocket);  // Socket
                                
            IF (SktClose_instance.Done=TRUE) THEN 
                Stage:=INT#0;  // Normal end
                TCP_Conn_Status:= _CLOSED;
            ELSIF (SktClose_instance.Error=TRUE) THEN
                error_ID:=(SktClose_instance.ErrorID);
                IF (SktClose_instance.ErrorID = WORD#16#2007) THEN//errrorID = 2007 --> Socket Handle Out of Range(closed)
                    Stage:=0;
                    //TCP_Conn_Status:= _CLOSED;
                ELSE
                    Stage:=INT#60;  // Error end
                END_IF;
                
            END_IF;
            
        0:  // Normal end
            DoTCP  :=FALSE;
            Done:= TRUE;
            
            SktTCPSend_instance(  // reinitialize instance.
                Execute:=FALSE,
                SendDat:= dummy_dat[0]);
            SktTCPRcv_instance( //reset instance
                Execute:=FALSE,
                RcvDat :=dummy_dat[0]); 
                
        ELSE  // Interrupted by error.
            IF (error_ID = WORD#16#2003 OR error_ID = WORD#16#2008) THEN //Socket Status Error
                    //Stage:=UINT#2;    //force reopen
                    //error_ID:=WORD#16#0;
                    TCP_Conn_Status:= _CLOSED;
                    //TCP_Conn_Status:= TCP_Conn_Status;
            END_IF;             
                DoTCP  :=FALSE;//use FALSE to reset states, use TRUE to trap error during debug
                Done := FALSE;              
                SktTCPSend_instance(  // reinitialize instance.
                    Execute:=FALSE,
                    SendDat:= dummy_dat[0]);
                SktTCPRcv_instance( //reset instance
                    Execute:=FALSE,
                    RcvDat :=dummy_dat[0]);
            //END_IF;
                
                
    END_CASE;
 
END_IF;
```

Comment: So, they just gave you this unreadable abomination and no protocol documentation?

Comment: (not a solution)There are a few options for this as far as communications are concerned. C# has a few embedded libraries for TCP/IP communications. I've done quite a bit of communications via TAP and EAP, the only advice I have there is if you're expecting more than 8+ devices, then use EAP, if you're expecting minimal number of devices, use TAP. 

Can you make your question more specific to allow for a solution? If you're looking for architecture analysis/design review, this may not be the best place to ask.

Comment: @Fildor Yeah, it is an abomination. I don't do structured text, there is no documentation, they have it working with labview, but I also don't do labview, I have their code, but it's really hard to follow... It's a bit of a shit show to be honest.

Comment: @Seeds Well, I was just looking for some pointers on how to do the TCP/IP in general. I'll figure out the rest. I was following this: www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/socket-programming-in-C-Sharp/ But so far I can't get it to work. Thanks anyway. I do realize that I might be in the wrong place asking this.

Comment: no worries @W.Donald, tcp/ip can get very device specific for communication behaviours. Hard to give generalized advice.